# How much experience does the enemy get when we deny a creep

Tags: dota-2

How much experience does the enemy get when we deny a creep? (if any)

And How much do we get? (if any)

Comment: Why do you want to know about a past version?

Comment: I want to know the most recent one, but according to this https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Denying 7.06 has the latest changes in the denying mechanic right?

Comment: No, that's not right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Patch 7.07**

Denied XP granted to the enemy (the player being denied) reduced from 70% to 25%.
Denied XP gained by the denier reduced from 30% to 25%.
Neutrals killing lane creeps is now considered the same as the enemy creeps killing them—it's not a deny, and gives full XP. You must deny the creep yourself to deny its XP.

Comment: this means both of us get 25% ?

Comment: Yes, if the enemy is in experience range (1500 as of 7.07)

Answer (score 2):

As of **[Patch 7.07c](http://www.dota2.com/duelingfates) (current)**

```
             | Normal | Denier | Enemy |
----------------------------------------
       Melee |     57 |     14 |    14 |
      Ranged |     69 |     17 |    17 |
       Siege |     88 |     22 |    22 |
 Any player- |    100%|      0%|     0%|
  controlled |        |        |       |
```

Source: [Gamepedia](https://dota2.gamepedia.com/Lane_creeps#Stats)